# How do I connect an Apple Mastercard to my Simplifi account?

Tags: apple-card

There is no option in the interface of Simplifi and no way to easily manage subscriptions on the Apple credit card. I would like to be able to manage my finances from one app, however it appears that the Apple credit card can not be used in this way.

Comment: What does sinplifi say about managing arbitrary credit cards? Apple has been clear that they don’t put your financial data on the web for privacy and security reasons by design. I believe the only [integrator to get a nod from Apple has been intuit for their mint product](https://mint.intuit.com/blog/how-to/you-can-now-connect-your-apple-card-to-mint/).